# how to create login with using binary files system

Tags: c#, web-applications, c#-2.0, application-design, programmers-notepad

i have used this code but not successes. can u give me solution or can u give me different way of coding it big help to improve my knowledge.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string s;
  string[] ss = s.Split(':');
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("UserFile.txt")) {
    s = reader.ReadLine();
  }

  if (txtUser.Text == ss[0]) {
    if (txtPass.Text == ss[1]) {
      this.Hide();
      Properties.Settings.Default.ss = txtUser.Text;
      Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
      frmMainMenu mf = new frmMainMenu();
      mf.Show();
    }
    else {
      MessageBox.Show("Sorry Wrong Password");
    }
  }
  else {
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry Wrong Username");
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your checking logic inside the stream reader

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("UserFile.txt"))
        {
           string s;
           s = reader.ReadLine();
           string[] ss = s.Split(':');
           if (txtUser.Text == ss[0])
           {
             if (txtPass.Text == ss[1])
             {
                this.Hide();
                Properties.Settings.Default.ss = txtUser.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                frmMainMenu mf = new frmMainMenu();
                mf.Show();
             }
             else
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry Wrong Password");
             }
           }  
           else
           {
             MessageBox.Show("Sorry Wrong Username");
           }
        }

   }
```

Comment: there s an error showing here = 
Properties.Settings.Default.ss = txtUser.Text;

Comment: check y0ur `Properties.Settings.Default.ss` is it valid or not, other than reading text and checking is working I think

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the split after you read the textfile.

```
string[] ss = File.ReadAllText("userfile.txt").Split(':');
```

Assuming that there is only one line in the textfile containing "username:password";

Comment: thank you,, can i have any simple different method to login '.'/

Comment: what do you mean by "login '.'/" ?

Comment: You'll have to define that property `ss` in the Project (right-click on Project -> Properties -> Settings) and set it to User Scope

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped, please accept and/or upvote

Comment: There are up and down arrows and a checkmark next to each answer.